# SSH in shell script with password

Tags: shell, ssh

I want to write  one shell script like

```
command1    
ssh vivek@remotehost 
    fire command on remote host
```

Now I have password in pass.txt . But when I change stdin with file. It is not reading password from file.

```
script.sh < password.txt
```

It is prompting for the password in place of reading password from the file. 
What I am doing wrong ?

Second problem is that shell script don't shows the command fired. Is there a way , I can show fired command from it ?

Note : 
I don't have key based access on remote system. I can only use password based login for ssh.

Comment: Do you have remote ssh server deliberately set up to *deny* key-based authorization, or you can't write to $HOME/.ssh directory? That's the only 2 ways I can think of why you can't use keys...

Comment: I don't have permission to write in $HOME/.ssh .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to automatically enter in shell password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8200461/way-to-automatically-enter-in-shell-password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ssh-agent or expect (the programing language) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH ssh does not reads the password from stdin but from /dev/tty. That's why you have to use Expect or some other similar tool to automate it.

[plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is another client, also available for Linux/Unix that accepts the password as a parameter on the command line... though that has some ugly security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, just to mention yet another option: [sshpass](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass) is a tool developed for exactly the task of "fooling" regular openssh client to accept password non-interactively.