# Way to automatically enter in shell password?

Tags: shell, ssh

So I have a script that ssh into another computer. Since I use it often, I was wondering if I could have the script automatically enter in the password prompted by ssh, or in any other way bypass copy-pasting the password every single time I run the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better setup up ssh keys with empty passphrase than putting your password in a script.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

Comment: By the way, would you know how to do this with SSH2? I generated a `id_dsa_1024_a.pub` file using `ssh-kegyen2`, tried to append it to `authorized_keys`, but still cannot login automatically.

Comment: @wrongusername - http://serverfault.com/questions/116177/whats-the-difference-between-authorized-keys-and-authorized-keys2

Comment: Hm, I tried `authorized_keys2` in both the `.ssh` and `.ssh2` folders and it still asks me for my password. The software is old though (last updated in 1997 I believe, still using version 1.2). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to have a passphrase-less private key on the client side, paired with a public key in the server-side authorized_keys file with a specific command that gets run.

For example, having the following in `.ssh/authorized_keys2` for the given user on the remote host:

```
command="date" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIw[...]Q== Comment for passphraseless key
```

Will *only* ever run `date` when you connect using that key:

```
[localhost] % ssh -i /path/to/id user@remotehost         
Sun 20 Nov 2011 20:29:59 EST
Connection to remotehost closed.
```