# ssh with password

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass password to su/sudo/ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233217/pass-password-to-su-sudo-ssh)
>   [SSH in shell scipt with password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191898/ssh-in-shell-scipt-with-password)

Is there any possibility I can pass password for ssh command

```
ssh root@10.20.30.40 | echo "Password" (or)      
echo "Password" | ssh root@10.20.30.40 (or) a script like below  
pw1="Password"
ssh -t root@168.56.64.245 <<< EOF  
$pw1  
EOF
```

Any solution can be helpful.

I was on windows and I was connecting to Linux host with putty and from that Linux to another Linux host. The problem is I can't use any 3rd party tools on Linux hosts and I can't add rsa-keys also.

Comment: I can't use tools like Expect.

Comment: Also both the Linux versions are SUSE 11 Sp2

Comment: Avoid doing that. Use public keys, and configure your `ssh` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can not add , but look if sshpass is installed

Answer (score 0):

Use `expect`. See [here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/)

I used it in one my projects. It was really helpful. It is a bit long to implement but the logic is easy - after the ssh "query" you just "expect" for something you wrote after the command expect as a regexp. Hope it helps.

Comment: Its restricted to use tools like Expect

Answer (score 0):

Use **expect**, here a script example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
    set timeout 20
    set IPaddress [lindex $argv 0]
    set Username "your_username"
    set Password "your_password"
    set Directory DIRECTORY_PATH

    log_file -a $Directory/session_$IPaddress.log
    send_log "### /START-TELNET-SESSION/ IP: $IPaddress @ [exec date] ###\r"

    spawn telnet $IPaddress
    expect "Username: "
    send "$Username\r"
    expect "Password: "
    send "$Password\r"
    interact
    send_log "\r### /END-TELNET-SESSION/ IP: $IPaddress @ [exec date] ###\r"
exit
```

**Source** : [Expect scripts for automatic login with telnet and SSH](http://smacak.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/automatic-login-expect-scripts-telnet-and-ssh/)

**EDIT**: If you dont want to use expect tool you should try to log using ssh key exchange

**EDIT2** : I read you dont wanna use except or key exchange but I'm not sure this could be accomplished without these.

Check this post:

[SSH Automatic Login](http://wp.uberdose.com/2006/10/16/ssh-automatic-login/)

Another option:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/

Comment: Thanks for you response but its restricted to use tools like Expect

Comment: Updated my answer. If you dont want to use expect tool you should try to log using ssh key exchange

Comment: Carlos Lande, please do refer the question. I can't use any 3rd party tools or ssh-keys. But Thank you.

Comment: I read it, but I think it is not possible. Password are meant to be introduced by human, the terminal is specting it so if you dont use certificate trust of external tools I think it can't be accomplished. I will check this question close, if there is a method I also would like to know it. Thanks ;)